# Visual Basic downloads json instead of reading it

Tags: json, vba

I am making a request to a webpage using Visual Basic and i want to parse the response and add it to a database. My problem is that when i make the request, Windows prompts a question that asks if i want to save the file. Is there a way to receive the response as string directly in VB?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
Dim ret As Long
Dim ie As Object

    'checking connection state

    ret = InternetGetConnectedStateEx(ret, sConnType, 254, 0)

    'instantiating IE
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    'hiding browser
    ie.Visible = False
    'opening link
     Header = "x-api-key:..." & Chr(10) & Chr(13)

    ie.Navigate "https://api.openapi.ro/api/companies/13548146", , , , Header
```

Comment: Are you using VB.Net or VBA? If it's VB.Net the answer is to use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or similar. Please ensure you tag your question correctly.

Comment: Use XMLHTTP instead of IE since you don't need to interact with the response.

Comment: Please specify whether you are using VBA or VB.Net - there are two very different answers to your question depending upon which one you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If this is VBA, I suggest using XMLHTTP.  In the VBA IDE, use tools--->references to add a reference to "Microsoft XML, v6.0" in the project (you may have a different version, adjust your code and references accordingly).

Here is an example of how you might use it:

```
Public Sub TestIt()
    Dim xh As XMLHTTP60
    Set xh = New XMLHTTP60

    With xh
        .Open "GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
        .send
    End With

    'In this case, the response text was in ASCII, so I had to use StrConv to convert it to Unicode for VBA.
    Debug.Print StrConv(xh.responseBody, vbUnicode)
End Sub
```